# How to show specific HTML div element when user is logged in? ASP.net MVC core 3.1 without entity framework

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to have the div hidden when user isnt logged in. I have heard something about ASP.identity and I have already tried something but it's still very ambiguous to me. I can already login and logout and get it inside a cookie. Also, I'd like to have "Logout" button popup on my navbar when user is logged in.

These are my codes (without model):

This is my Login view:

```
<center>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form asp-action="Login" method="post">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
        <input type="submit" onclick="CheckNullOrEmpty()" value="Login" />
        <h1>@Html.ViewData["Message"]</h1>

    </form>
</center>
```

This is my Usercontroller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            try
            {

            sqlconn.Open();

            string sqlquery = "SELECT Username,Password FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password;";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.Username);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.Password);

            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdr.Read())
                {

                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username)
                    };

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
                    HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();

                    return RedirectToAction("AdminPaneel", "User");
                }

            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Foute gegevens ingevuld!";
            }
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
            return View();
        } 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Home");
    }
}
```

This is the Div Element inside xView I want to display when Im logged in:

```
    <div class="form-check" id="discountCheck">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="kortingChecked">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">5% discount</label>
            </div>
```

This is the HTML code of xView:

```
<header class="Header">
    <div id="myMenu">
        <div class="myWrapper">
            <nav>
                <a href="/"><img id="imgComp" src="../images/vd.png" height="100" width="250" /></a>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<br />




<div class="GegevensReiziger">

    <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:25px;">Naam/adres van de aanmelder/hoofdboeker</h3>
    <p style="font-style: oblique;">* Verplicht veld</p>
    <br />

    <div class="PersoonlijkeDetails">


        <div>
            <label>Aanhef:</label><br /><select><option value="1"> Heer </option> <option value="2"> Mevrouw </option></select>
            <br />
            <label>Voornaam:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="firstName" Name="FirstName" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
            <br />
            <label>Achternaam:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="lastName" Name="Achternaam" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
            <br />
            <label>Geboortedatum:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="birthDate" Name="Geboortedatum" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
            <br />
            <label>Woonplaats/Postcode:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="wplaats" Name="Woonplaats" Size=15 Maxlength=15> <input id="postcode" class="postcode" type="text" />
            <br />
            <label>Straat/Huisnummer:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="strnaam" Name="Straat" Size=15 Maxlength=15 /> <input id="huisnr" class="huisnr" type="text" />
            <br />
            <label>Nationaliteit:*</label><br /><select id="nationality" class="dropdown-menu-lg-right" name="nationality">
                <option value="">Kies je nationaliteit</option>
                <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
                <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
                <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
                <option value="american">American</option>
                <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
                <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
                <option value="antiguans">Antiguans</option>
                <option value="argentinean">Argentinean</option>
                <option value="armenian">Armenian</option>
                <option value="australian">Australian</option>
                <option value="austrian">Austrian</option>

            </select>
            <br />
            <label>Telefoonnummer:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="telnr" Name="Nationaliteit" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
            <br />
            <label>E-mail:*</label><br /><Input type="text" id="email" Name="email">
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="reizigerconf" name="reizigerconf" value="reiziger">Aanmelder is ook reiziger.
            <br />
            <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnToevoegen" onclick=""> Doorgaan</button>
            <br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /><br />

<div style="" class="Reis-boeking">

    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Reisgezelschap</h3>
    <p style="font-style:oblique; text-align:center;">*Verplichte veld</p>
    <div class="Reiziger1">
        <div class="Reiziger1Box">
            <div class="reizigergegevens1">
                <p style="font-size:medium; ">1e reiziger.</p>
                <label id="aanhef">Aanhef:</label><br /><select id="aanhefCh"><option value="1"> Heer </option> <option value="2"> Mevrouw </option></select>
                <br />
                <br />
                <Input type="text" Name="Name" id="NameReiziger" placeholder="Voornaam*" Size=15 Maxlength=15> <Input type="text" Name="Achternaam" id="AchternaamReiziger" placeholder="Achternaam*" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
                <br />
                <br />
                <Input type="text" Name="Woonplaats" id="WpReiziger" placeholder="Woonplaats*" Size=15 Maxlength=15> <input class="postcode" id="PcReiziger" placeholder="Postcode*" type="text" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Input type="text" Name="Straat" id="StrReiziger" placeholder="Straat*" Size=15 Maxlength=15 /> <input class="huisnr" id="HuisnrReiziger" placeholder="Huisnr*" type="text" />
                <br />
                <br /><select class="nationality" name="nationality">
                    <option value="">Kies je nationaliteit</option>
                    <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
                    <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
                    <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
                    <option value="american">American</option>
                    <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
                    <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
                    <option value="antiguans">Antiguans</option>
                    <option value="argentinean">Argentinean</option>
                    <option value="armenian">Armenian</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <br /><Input type="text" Name="Nationaliteit" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnr" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
                <br /> <br /><button class="btn-outline-primary" id="btnToevoegen1"> Toevoegen </button>
                <a id="wijzigenReiziger"> Reisgezelschap wijzigen. </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="Reiziger2">
    <div class="Reiziger2Box">
        <p style="font-size:medium; ">2e reiziger.</p>
        <label id="aanhef">Aanhef:</label><br /><select id="aanhefCh"><option value="1"> Heer </option> <option value="2"> Mevrouw </option></select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Input type="text" id="NameReiziger" Name="Name" placeholder="Voornaam*" Size=15 Maxlength=15> <Input type="text" Name="Achternaam" id="AchternaamReiziger" placeholder="Achternaam*" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Input type="text" Name="Woonplaats" id="WpReiziger" placeholder="Woonplaats*" Size=15 Maxlength=15> <input class="postcode" id="PcReiziger" placeholder="Postcode*" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Input type="text" Name="Straat" id="StrReiziger" placeholder="Straat*" Size=15 Maxlength=15 /> <input class="huisnr" id="HuisnrReiziger" placeholder="Huisnr*" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br /><select class="nationality" name="nationality">
            <option value="">Kies je nationaliteit</option>
            <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
            <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
            <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
            <option value="american">American</option>
            <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
            <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
            <option value="antiguans">Antiguans</option>
            <option value="argentinean">Argentinean</option>
            <option value="armenian">Armenian</option>
            <option value="australian">Australian</option>

        </select>
        <br />
        <br /><Input type="text" Name="nr" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnr" Size=15 Maxlength=15>
        <br /><br /><button class="btn-outline-primary" id="btnToevoegen1"> Toevoegen </button>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
            Click me!
            <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If I understand properly, try this code in your view

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{


      <div class="form-check" id="discountCheck">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="kortingChecked">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">5% discount</label>
        </div>

}
```

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't display the Div element eventhough I've logged in.

Comment: Please check your startup.cs class Configure Method : these two middleware added or not: app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: I've fixed in a another way with ur code. Thank you brother.

Comment: also check ConfigureServices Method   services.AddAuthentication mothod you added or not